# Constructing the Hodge Laplacian from the Laplace-Beltrami one

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds, laplacian, hodge-theory

I know, in principle, how to construct the Hodge Laplacian with the aid of the Hodge star. Is it possible, though, to construct it only from the Laplace-Beltrami operator? I have already found a way, using the Bochner Laplacian and [Weitzenböck's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck_identity), is this the only one known?